# How to assign extracted substring to variable in bash?

Tags: bash

In bash shell how do we assign extracted substring into variable without 'bad substitution' errors, please?

For example with the codes below:

```
fruit="apple"
echo $fruit | cut -c1-3

variable=$"{echo $fruit | cut -c1-3}"
```

The second line returns 'app' but the third line can't really work without bad substitution error.

Comment: Where did you get the idea to use `$"{...}"` to surround the command?

Comment: The third line should simply assign a literal string to `variable` without running any commands or producing any sort of error.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
variable=$"{echo $fruit | cut -c1-3}"
```

with

```
variable=$(echo $fruit | cut -c1-3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a dream now. I was wondering why do we use parenthesis instead of ${} as we do for other scalar variable assignments?

Answer (score 1):

do this instead

```
$ fruit=apple; var="${fruit:0:3}"; echo "$var"
app
```